# replace jsx elements in rendered tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I want to replace element in jsx e.g  react tiny Link npm is rendering this

```
<div>
<header>
header
</header>
 hello
 <footer>
 footer
 </footer>
</div>
```

and i want to replace header and footer tag with div like this

```
<div>
<div>
 header
 </div>
hello
<div >
footer
</div>
</div>
```

react tiny link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tiny-link) and Im working on accessibility in React application its creating this above code but this deque [extension](https://www.deque.com/axe/browser-extensions/) raising issue that you can't have multiple header on same page. the first main header is created by me
Im also having other issues like role="rowgroup" which are on other pages"

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't want to replace a [semantic html](https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/NOTE-html53-20210128/dom.html#elements-semantics) element such as a `<header>` with a non-semantic element such as a `<div>` or `<span>`.

A `<header>` typically contains the main navigation to a page and is displayed at the top.

The [official HTML 5.3 spec for `<header>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element) does **not** say that you can't have more than one `<header>`, although it would be unusual and not a best practice to do so.

However, a `<header>` has a [default role](https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-header) of [`banner`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#banner) as long as it's not a child element of an `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<main>`, `<nav>` or `<section>` element, and the `banner` role says:

> Within any document or application, the author SHOULD mark no more than one element with the banner role.

The key here is the word "[SHOULD](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-3)", meaning it's *recommended* that you shouldn't have more than one banner but it's not strictly prohibited.

So with all that being said, if you are trying to change your `<header>` to a `<div>` because an accessibility tool is flagging it as an **error**, then that tool is incorrect.  If the tool is marking it as a **warning** or something you should manually verify, then you can ignore the warning **if** you have a good reason for having two `<header>` elements.

I know this doesn't answer your main question of **how** to change it, but it might make your question irrelevant if you don't **need** to change it.